# NullPointerException when I run this code

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

So in this code, I am trying to retrieve a cursor based on the query passed through my `showResults()` and then create an `adapter` and `loadermanager`. I feel like the problem is being caused with the layout and id within my `SimpleCursorAdapter` constructor because the error started when I created the layout and id. I used Log and if statement to see whether it was the cursor that was null and nothing showed up on the logcat, so that must mean by cursor is fine.

```
public class SearchResultsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

private ListView list;
private DatabaseTable db;
private SimpleCursorAdapter mAdapter;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_search_results);
    db = new DatabaseTable(this);
    handleIntent(getIntent());
}

public void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    setIntent(intent);
    handleIntent(intent);
}

private void handleIntent(Intent intent) {
     if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
        showResults(query);
    }

}

private void showResults(String query) {
    db = new DatabaseTable(this);
    Cursor cursor = db.getContactMatches(query, null);
    list = (ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, 
            null, new String[] {DatabaseTable.COL_NAME}, new int[] {android.R.id.text1}, 0);
    getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
    list.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Intent contactIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ContactActivity.class);
            contactIntent.setData(getIntent().getData());
            startActivity(contactIntent);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: what line do you get the error at?

Comment: Post your logcat output too.

Comment: And again, I am not totally sure if it is the id and layout that is causing the problem and even if I did, I wouldn't know how to set the layout to simple_list_item_1 kind of like what you do with the id within the xml file

Comment: What? If you are not sure which causes the error, is there any problem to post your logcat output here? Questions are posted when the OP is not sure about the problem. Quite prevalent.

Comment: 01-02 21:58:33.291: E/AndroidRuntime(595): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myfirstapp/com.example.myfirstapp.SearchResultsActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-02 21:58:33.291: E/AndroidRuntime(595):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
01-02 21:58:33.291: E/AndroidRuntime(595): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-02 21:58:33.291: E/AndroidRuntime(595):  at com.example.myfirstapp.SearchResultsActivity.showResults(SearchResultsActivity.java:57)

Comment: it seems to be at the line list.setAdapter(mAdapter);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your code is crashing on the line `list.setAdapter(mAdapter);`, `list` is the only object that it makes sense to give you a null pointer.

Upon further examination, it is clear you are not assigning `list` after it is initially declared. You need to add something like this in `onCreate()`, after `setContentView()`:

```
list = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
```

*(This is how you'd access it if your object had `android:id="@android:id/list"`; if you assigned your own ID, use `R.id.your_id_here` instead.)*

Comment: would it make a difference if I was doing it within showResults()?

Comment: @SaiValluri No, except that in general, member variables should be assigned as soon as possible, so that all methods can use them. By putting it in `onCreate()`, you won't have to move it later when something else needs `list` before `handleIntent()`.

Comment: @SaiValluri I see why you asked that, now. Something seems amiss here--you're using `android.R.id.list` without a `ListFragment`. Can you post your `activity_search_results.xml` file?

Comment: <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@android:id/text1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="62dp"
         />

</RelativeLayout>

Comment: @SaiValluri I meant to edit it into the first post... but okay! Anyway, there is no element in there which is a `ListView`. That's why it's null.

Comment: should I create a new activity_search_results.xml, but make it a ListView instead of a RelativeLayout? Or can I just add the listview within my relativeLayout?

Comment: @SaiValluri Just add the list within your existing layout. It should belong alongside the `TextView` you have already, I suspect...

Answer (score 0):

this is probably your error here:

```
mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, 
            null, new String[] {DatabaseTable.COL_NAME}, new int[] {android.R.id.text1}, 0);
```

that adapter requires a `Cursor` passed into the constructor at the spot where you passed `null` in for the parameter, like this:

```
mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, 
            cursor, new String[] {DatabaseTable.COL_NAME}, new int[] {android.R.id.text1}, 0);
```

Comment: that doesn't seem to fix the error, but I understand that putting cursor in the parameter was necessary.

Comment: I am going to check this off once I fix the null exception because this definitely would have been a problem in the future.

Comment: thanks. but it looks like Eric got the correct solution to your problem, no?

Comment: Yes it did work. Sorry that I can't give you the check, I wouldn't have noticed the cursor error.

Comment: it's 'kay. :D i'm just glad we got to the bottom of it!

Answer (score 0):

Try getting a readable database first before you query it:

```
db = new DatabaseTable(this);
Cursor cursor = db.getReadableDatabase().getContactMatches(query, null);
```

Comment: I think only the DBHelper can actually get a readable database.

Comment: But I do have an open() method within my database class, should I just do that and then close it?

Comment: Do you have something like:
public SqliteDatabase openDB() {
    return this.getReadableDatabase();
}

Comment: Yes, I do. Again, should I close it right when I get finished initializing my cursor?